# What is the process of SOLR support team?

Tags: solr, search-engine

I am little bit curious about to know what are the maintenance and support process followed by the SOLR support team?

Is there any special life cycle followed by SOLR support team?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Solr is an open source Apache project. The only support you will get is the open source community and forums. If you like more enterprise level support then consider using Elasticsearch, Lucid Imagination search products or any other enterprise search products out there.